# Java setters and "this"

Tags: java

I have noticed in alot of people do in Java setters:

1)

```
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
```

Personally I don't like this and I think it should be something like:

2)

```
public void setX(int newX) {
    x = newX;
}
```

Are there any reasons the first would be better?

Isn't 1) easier to make an error with. On a few occassions I have tracked bugs in code down to people doing:

```
x = x;
```

by mistake, maybe because they were typing to fast and just wanted to get the getters and setters out of the way.

Comment: I prefer the first option as well. Not sure why this is being downvoted though.

Comment: Eclipse automatically uses the this.x = x style when generating getters and setters. That might be why so many people use that style.

Comment: I prefer the second form, not always using `newX` as argument name, but `this.x = x;` is a form of variable hiding and therefore something I would not use.

Comment: In my experience, errors using the second form is massively more common.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a matter of style.  The argument in favor of

```
public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
```

is that you don't need to think of a new and meaningful name for the input argument, since you already have one.

Pick a style and use it *consistently*.

Answer (score 7):

Reasons to prefer `this.x = x`:

1. Using `this.x = x` in constructors and is a known pattern, which Java programmers recognize.
2. The `x` in both the field and parameter represent the same value.
3. With `x = newX` there is no syntactic indication that one is a field and the other a parameter.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a "better" or "worse" here. It's just a matter of style.

Comment: Isn't the first easier to make an error with. On a few occassions I have tracked bugs in code down to people doing: x=x; by mistake, maybe because they were typing to fast and just wanted to get the getters and setters out of the way  :)

Comment: Who types getters and setters?  All worthwhile IDEs will generate them for you.  If you happen to "type too fast", all worthwhile IDEs will tell you right away that "x=x" is wrong.

Comment: Why are you typing your simple setters by yourself anyways? Run eclipse, click, click, done.

Comment: I don't rush through the code myself, but I can't stop others rushing through it

Answer (score 3):

It's just a coding convention. You're free to choose, but use it **consitently**. Also, an average IDE can autogenerate all getters/setters in a few keystrokes/clicks. In Eclipse for example, do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and then <kbd>S</kbd> and then select the properties you'd like to generate getters/setters for and click OK. Also, an average IDE will display a warning when you do `x = x` instead of `this.x = x`.

I myself prefer the `this.x = x`. Eclipse and many reverse-engineer tools (like Dali and Hibernate Tools) also generates it that way by default.

The `x = newX` convention (the [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)) is just inherited from the (old-fashioned) procedural programming world and simply doesn't fit nicely in the OO ideology.

Comment: Do the reverse enginnering tools require "this.x = x" to be used to understand it?

Comment: No, it's just a standard convention they adhere.

Comment: Yes, your right. I guess I grew up on Microsoft C and C++, and so Hungarian notation was one of those things I never grew out of, but maybe I should have :)

Answer (score 3):

It's entirely subjective, but the first form provides a nice clear method prototype in javadoc etc.

I don't feel there's much scope for error using the 'this.x = x' form. Certainly nothing that won't get caught by unit tests. You do have unit tests, right?

Comment: I have unit tests yes, and always write them, but you would be surprised at how many projects I've gone onto where they have hardly any code coverage at all in their unit tests.

Comment: Yes. Using a funky name for the parameter (like newX or pX) just makes the JavaDocs look bad.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer `this.x = x;`. There is really no right way on this. In an IDE, it will look good for the extra color on `this`.

Answer (score 2):

If it's your own code or not part of an existing base pick the one you like and stick with it. If however you are working with existing code follow whatever convention is already being used.

Comment: Yes, I agree, convention is more important sometimes

Answer (score 1):

I assume that setters are auto-generated by the IDE. So my preference is the form that is used by default in the IDE. That is to say, I'm fairly neutral on it and feel that it does not merit changing the default IDE settings.